# How to use atomizer (automatic css generator for atomic css) extension on VSCode?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, atomic

can someone help me. I really want to use atomic css in my project. I see in vscode that there's atomizer extension that generates atomic css classes but I'm had a hard time using it. I don't know how to use it. I read the guide but still can't. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the "[vscode-atomizer](https://github.com/acss-io/vscode-atomizer)" extension?
If yes, then you need to have a config file (atomizer.json) in the root of your project for this extension to work.